# How to change the time format based on its data

Tags: gnuplot

Do you know how to change the time format based on its data?
I'd like to add Year info on the X axis if the date is January like this.

```
2013/01/01, 02/01, 03/01, ..., 11/01, 12/01, 2014/01/01, 02/21,....
```

I know **set format** command to change it.

```
set format x "%m/%d"
```

or

```
set format x "%Y/%m/%d"
```

But I don't know how to customize it.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use year only one time?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

No. Whenever January appear, it should be displayed with year info.
I'm developing a simple chart program like this.
http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AAPL+Interactive#symbol=AAPL;range=5y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not so straightforward, because, as you said, with gnuplot you can set only a single format without any conditionals.

You can solve this by setting the year info manually with `set xtics add`, like it was also done in the very similar question [mixing date and time on gnuplot xaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883155/mixing-date-and-time-on-gnuplot-xaxis).

Here is a working script:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
set format x '%m/%d'
set xrange ['2013-01-01 00:00':*]
set xtics '2013-01-01 00:00', 3*30*24*60*60

set xtics add ('2013/01/01' '2013-01-01 00:00', '2014/01/01' '2014-01-01 00:00')

plot 'data.dat' using 1:3 with linespoints
```

So, you first set the format of your input data. Here I've explicitly chosen a different input format, so that you can distinguish where you need which format.

Then you set the output format for the x-axis, which corresponds to what you want for the intermediate months.

Next I explicitly set a start value for the xrange, so that the range starts with January (because I set a label only every three months, with `set xtics ...`).

As a last step you manually overwrite the January labels with your custom format. In this form it may be a bit cumbersome if you have several years or if you want to be flexible. It is not a problem to iterate over a range of years. The labels which are outside of the displayed range are ignored. So you could use:

```
set for [y=2000:2014] xtics add (sprintf('%d/01/01', y) ''.y.'-01-01 00:00')
```

(Note, that `sprintf` cannot be used for the second string.)

With the following test data file `data.dat`:

```
2013-01-01 00:00 12
2013-02-01 12:00 15
2013-04-01 00:00 1
2013-12-01 00:00 11
2014-01-01 14:00 14
2014-04-01 03:00 20
```

I get the result (using 4.6.5):

[image: plot showing result]