# Overriding tick labels in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file containing data like this:

```
   Date          Hour         Data
2014/01/01        00            5
2014/01/01        01            10
2014/01/01        02            7
2014/01/01        03            6
.
.
.
2014/01/01        23            4
2014/01/02        00            6
2014/01/02        01            9
2014/01/02        02            2
.
.
.
```

I want to plot the file in gnuplot with "Data" on y axis and "Hour" on x axis which I know how to do that. I also want that when "Hour" value is "00" (or at the changing of dates) the related "Date" appears on the x axis instead of "Hour". any idea?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300032/how-to-change-the-time-format-based-on-its-data)

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, its a duplicate of that question, the solution works fine for me after adapting the time formats. I voted for closing this one here.