# Gnuplot different tick format for start of month

Tags: gnuplot

I've started to use gnuplot for time-series data recently, and would like to know if there's a way to automatically apply special formatting to some xtics.

For example, I would like to use `%d` as the default format string, but on the 1st each month use `%b`, so that the xlabels would read `...26,27,28,29,30,Dec,02,03,04....`.

So far I can use `set xtics add ("Dec" "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z")`, but for that to work I have to parse the data, extract the range and explicitly add a tic for each month. Are there better alternatives?

Comment: No, unfortunately you must parse the data and set the extra tics. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25304926/2604213 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883697/2604213 to get started

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, I completely missed those other questions you linked.